# Make/Makes Confusion

Tags: agreement

Can anyone help explain to me why the answer to the following question is what it is.

> The Navajo language is complex, with a structure and sound that **makes** it unintelligible to anyone without extensive exposure to it.

On the answer key, it states that answer is "make" and not "makes". Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Probably because it's referring to both the structure and the sound at the same time. Somehow it does sound odd to my ears.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, but the antecedent appears to be "The Navajo Language" which is singular resulting in "makes".

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's a decent answer right there. +1

Comment: Related: [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346), [Should “was” or “were” be used here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264048)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singular verb after two noun phrases joined by "and" that can be thought of as a single thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97459/singular-verb-after-two-noun-phrases-joined-by-and-that-can-be-thought-of-as-a)

Comment: @G.B. - the subject (antecedent) of 'make[s]' is NOT 'language', but rather the coordinated pair.  The coordination is clumsy in that 'sound' is not 'a sound' or 'sounds', so the the first article 'a' before 'structure' seems to apply to the pair, making it singular.

Comment: @Aml - Yup. I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although both singular *make* and plural *makes* could work, the simplest approach is to look at the two reasons that make the language hard to follow. Two reasons **make** it unintelligible.

The object pronoun 'it' (and its faraway subject antecedent 'language') does not come into play for the verb *make*, only its own subject (structure & sound) or subjects (structure and sound).

Structure and sound form two subjects. You could push it and say the structure and sound together form a barrier (a singular subject) to parsing Navajo, but since you say the answer key wants *make*, we can justify that answer.